# Invalid Credentials When Using Guzzle to make an Authentication

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make an Authentication system using guzzle but turn out it throwing this error:

```
Client error: `POST http://example.com/api/login` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"invalid_credentials"}
```

I've already checked the API url with the correct key and value in Postman and i got the right response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEwMCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2Rldi50b2tvaGFqaS5jby5pZC9hcGkvbG9naqwegzxvhyXQiOjE1OTE1NDU3NTUsImV4cCIasdqwegfxdzc6MTU5Mjc1NTM1NSwibmJmIjoxNTkxNTQ1NzU1LCJqdGkiOiJ2QmpZVHhaYXBYNjNvb21XIn0.RAKbWMSjk6I20LxczS9TFEUKV3f7t_fg84q89nhavN8"
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
        'login' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $client = new Client;
        $response = $client->post('http://example.com/api/login', [
            'form-data' => [
               'login' => $request->login, 
               'password' => $request->password
            ]
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($response)) {

            if (!empty (Auth::users())) {

                $events = $response['success'];
                foreach($events as $item)
                {
                   DB::table('users')->insert(['phone'=>$item['phone'], 'password'=>$item['password']]);
                   return redirect()->intended('/');
                }

            } else {
                // Authentication passed...
                return redirect()->intended('/');
            }
        }

        return Redirect::to('ecommerce.login')->withSuccess('Invalid credentials');

    }
```

Explanation: Here i'm trying to post the value to the API url, if it success and database has no data about it then the user login data (phone number and password) will be saved to application database and user will be logged in, else = user will straight away go to the home page. And if it failed user will be returned to the login page.

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/login', 'Ecommerce\FrontController@login')->name('front.login');
Route::post('post-login', [ 'as' => 'post-login', 'uses' => 'Ecommerce\LoginController@postLogin']);
```

Here is my blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('post-login') }}" method="post">
      @csrf
      <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center" style="color:#00843D;">
           <p style="padding-top:20px;">Welcome</p>
      </div>
      <hr>

      <div class="form-group">

           <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('login') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Phone Number" value="{{ old('login') }}" autofocus required>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">

           <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('login') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

           @if (count($errors) > 0)
               <div class="alert alert-danger">
               <ul>
               @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
               @endforeach
               </ul>
               </div>
           @endif

           <button class="registerbtn" type="submit">Login</button>
      </div>

      </div>

      <div class="container signin" style="padding-bottom:30px;">
           <p>Doesn't have account? <a href="{{ route('front.register') }}">Register in here</a>.</p>
      </div>
</form>
```

I've been trying to solve it for quite much time but still not found the answer. Hope you can help me, thank you.

Edit: [Here is the image from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTv2w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

So i try to find some reference about what it looks like if the API is on full url and it leads me to the answer!

And here is, I change my Controller to this:

```
$login = $request->login;
$password = $request->password;

$client = new Client;
$response = $client->post('http://example.com/api/login?login='.$login.'&password='.$password);

$json = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

Thank you @JoeGalind for helping me! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the body first.

After:

```
$response = $client->post('http://example.com/api/login', [
    'form-data' => [
        'login' => $request->login, 
        'password' => $request->password
    ]
]);

$json = json_decode((string) $response->getBody());
```

Just then, you have the json from your response to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's still throwing the same error: " Client error: `POST http://example.com/api/login` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"invalid_credentials"} " I think it has something to do with $response but i have no idea what it is, i've changed the 'form-data' to 'auth' as what mentioned in guzzle documentation but the result is: " Undefined offset: 0 ".

Comment: How are you sending the information from Postman? Please share a screenshot to see the correct configuration you are using

Comment: I've added it in the post, sorry i can't give you the exact url. There is no Authorization/Headers/Pre-request Script/Tests, only Body.

Comment: What version of Guzzle are you using?

Comment: i think it's the latest, which is version 7